# Failed to fetch on apt-get update

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, update-manager

I'm running into the following error when I run `sudo apt-get update`:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this or how it should best be resolved?

Comment: This looks like a server-side mishap that should be fixed soon; meanwhile you can use another mirror as the answer indicates.

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this same problem. I fixed it by changing the Download Location in Software & Updates settings. Seems that the UK Mirror has issues with this repo.

[image: Software & Updates]

Comment: Yeah, definitely a server issue. It's good that it has a few alternatives.